# Put variable in WordPress shortcode with Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, shortcode, rating, timber

I use Timber for WordPress and I installed a rating plugin (Yet Another Stars Rating plugin). The users can vote for movies.

This plugin use shortcode to display vote result and vote system.

I have a list of movies and I would like to display vote system for each movie.

I created my query in a movie template : **tpl_movies.php**

```
$context['movies'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

And a loop in my twig file : **tpl_movies.twig**

```
{% for item in movies %}
  <ul class="movies__list">
    <li>{{ item.title }} - Vote : {% filter shortcodes %} [yasr_overall_rating postid="{{ item.ID }}"] {% endfilter %}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to put `{{ item.ID }}` in my shortcode :

```
[yasr_overall_rating postid="{{ item.ID }}"]
```

**But that don't work.**

I can vote for the current page (who display the list of movies) but not for each movie.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/744) syntax? I think with that syntax it would be `<li>{{ item.title }} - Vote : {{ function('do_shortcode', '[yasr_overall_rating postid=' ~ item.ID ~ ']') }}</li>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JoshuaT. I will try today and I will give you a feed-back

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Joshua T in the comments above should work, it uses twig's string concatenation operator `~` to feed the correct string into the `do_shortcode` function.

If you're interested in going deeper though, and learning more about Timber then you have a couple methods there.

Timber has some guidelines on this you can check out on [the official documentation.](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/#functions-that-echo-output)

Firstly, all shortcodes are a wrapper for an output function - when you register a shortcode, you tell WordPress what the associated output function is.

For this scenario it's `shortcode_overall_rating_callback()`, and it expects an array of `$atts` as all shortcodes do.

so you could do something like this...

```
{# call the function directly from the twig template #}

{% for item in movies %}
    <ul class="movies__list">
        <li>{{ item.title }} - Vote : {{ function('shortcode_overall_rating_callback', { postid: item.id }) }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

If each movie has a rating, then you could look at extending it's "model" to encompass this functionality.

Conceptually, this is nice, as it means each movie can output it's own rating, anywhere you fetch them, rather than having it tied just to this one template you're writing.

To do this you'd extend `Timber\Post` and get the movies as this custom Post model, instead of the stock `Timber\Post`.

```
/* Somewhere in your theme, ensure it gets loaded, inc/models/Movie.php as an example */
<?php


namespace YourName\YourProject;
use \Timber\Post;
 
class Movie extends Post {

    public function get_rating_html(){
        if ( ! function_exists( 'shortcode_overall_rating_callback' ) ) return '';
        /* Can add other attributes to the array provided here */
        return shortcode_overall_rating_callback( [ 'postid' => $this->id, ] );
    }

}
```

Then in your PHP template for context building, you tell Timber to use that class instead of the default, by passing the classname as the second argument to `get_posts()`.

```
$queryArgs = [
  'post_type' => 'movies',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'order' => 'ASC'
];

$context['movies'] = Timber::get_posts( $queryArgs, \YourName\YourProject\Movie::class );
```

Finally in our twig template, we can access the custom method..

```
{% for item in movies %}
  <ul class="movies__list">
    <li>{{ item.title }} - Vote : {{ item.get_rating_html }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

These examples do use some things like namespaces and modern PHP syntax, but if you're using Timber, you're already on a version of PHP that supports this.

Finally, if you're using custom Post objects a lot, Timber has an awesome filter called `Timber\PostClassMap` where you can add your own mappings per post-type so you dont need to supply the custom post class name every time and can just `new PostQuery( $args );` or `Timber::get_posts($args)` and you'll get back the custom post classes matching your post type.. it's magic once you begin to use it!